# Django django.contrib.sites where to put migration?

Tags: python, django, django-models

the django doc says to change the sites name and domain in the django.contrib.sites framework one should use a migration [1].

But they forgot to mention where I should put this migration. I tried to create a directory named "sites" and a directory named "django.contrib.sites". But no matter in which directory I put my migration, `manage.py migration` always says there is nothing to update.

I also tried to run `python manage.py makemigrations --empty sites`, but then the migration is created in the lib directory: `ve/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/sites/migrations/0003_auto_20160904_2144.py`. This may be correct behaviour, but then I cannot set my change under source control.

In case something is wrong with my migration, here it is:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models

def set_site_name(apps, schema_editor):
    Sites = apps.get_model('django.contrib.sites', 'site')
    site = Sites.objects.filter(id=1).first()
    if site != None:
        site.name = "name"
        site.domain = "name.com"

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    initial = True

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(set_site_name),
    ]
```

So my question is: where does django expect to find those migrations?

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

[1] https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/sites/#enabling-the-sites-framework

Comment: Just for future reference: it is not needed to alter the "example.com" entry. If you just insert your own entry the "example.com" entry never appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each app in a Django project must have a unique [label](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.label). Naming your app `sites` isn't a good idea - it will clash with the `django.contrib.sites` app unless you change the label in the app config class.

If you have an existing app specific to your project, you could use that app to store the data migration.

Alternatively choose a different name like `mysites`. Create the app with `./manage.py startapp mysite`, add the app to your `INSTALLED_APPS`, then create a blank migration.

Comment: Don't forget to add a dependency on the `sites` app in your migration, as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/migrations/#accessing-models-from-other-apps).

Comment: The sites app I'm talking about _is_ `django.contrib.sites`. I want to rename the "example.com" entries so they fit my actual site names.

Comment: As you realise, you shouldn't add the migration to the ``django.contrib.sites` directory, because it's not your app, and it's not under your source control. Add the migration to a different app instead (either choose an existing app under source control, or create a new one like `mysites` as I suggested).

Comment: Ok, I introduced an "initial*" app. Thank you very much.